# Popen() class could not terminate

Tags: python, popen

So I had created a `Popen` class that executes a program with no natural termination, and I need to close it. The thing is, I cannot wait for the program to respond as it is always waiting for new `stdin` input, so I need to force terminate it. Here is my code for killing it:

```py
def stop_server():
    global log, procpid
    if procpid:
        os.kill(procpid, signal.SIGTERM)
        log = [("red", "Stopped")]
        procpid = 0
```

but, this does not work and the program still responds to events and inputs. I wanted a function that acts like closing the `X` button when opening the program manually in command line.

```py
def stop_server():
    global log, procpid
    if procpid:
        os.kill(procpid, signal.SIGTERM)
        log = [("red", "Server stopped")]
        procpid = 0
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a difference between the two versions of `stop_server()` that you posted?

Comment: What is the program? Doesn't have a handler for the `TERM` signal?

Comment: Instead of having a global variable with the pid, use a global variable containing the process, and use `process.pid`

Comment: Programs that wait for input on stdin usually terminate when they read EOF. So close the pipe connected to its stdin.

Comment: Have you tried `process.terminate()` or `process.kill()`

Comment: @TheTridentGuy of course! but it just still doesnt work

Comment: @Barmar the program is a Spigot server, but it does correctly close when i manually click the X button

Comment: Clicking the X button doesn't send a signal, it uses the window manager's protocol to close the window.

Comment: @Barmar thats interesting. is there anyway i can automate it?

Comment: Maybe with pyautogui?

Comment: But killing the process should also work. it's possible that it creates child processes, so killing the parent doesn't kill the rest of the app.

Comment: i tried using `Popen.kill()` and `Popen.terminate()`, but it just doesn't terminate it